# Authenticate users with Api Key

Tags: symfony, authentication, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I am trying to authenticate a user with an Api Key.
Using the symfony api key authentication guide:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.4/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html

the problem i'm encoutering is that I want to change that instead of using the FOSUserBundle:User Entity, then I will use my own custom entity. which will only have 2 fields for example: `name` and `api_key`.

I don't have an idea on how to approach it. and I've been trying for days to solve it.
Any ideas on what should I do in order to change it to work with my own custom "user" entity whic has only 2 fields?

Comment: What part of the Symfony documentation is tripping you up? It gives pretty clear examples on how to do everything you want to do